# Sas value counting

Tags: sas, counting

I am wanting to count the number of time a certain value appears in a particular column in sas. For example in the following dataset the value 1 appears 3 times
value 2 appears twice, value 3 appears once, value 4 appears 4 times and value 5 appears four times.

```
Game_ball  
  1
  1 
  1
  2
  2
  3
  4
  4
  4
  5  
  5
  5
  5
  5
```

I want the dataset to represented like the following:

```
Game_ball       Count
    1             3
    2             2
    3             1
    4             4 
    5             4
    .             .
    .             .
    .             .
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `proc freq`: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/63104/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_freq_sect006.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @Dwal, `proc freq` is the easiest solution.

Using your sample data,

```
proc freq data=sample; 
table game_ball/out=output;
run;
```

Or do it in one-pass data step

```
proc sort data = sample;by game_ball;run;

data output;
set sample;
retain count;
if first.game_ball then count = 0;
count + 1;
if last.game_ball then output;
by game_ball;
run;
```

Or in SQL

```
proc sql;
create table output as
select game_ball, count(*) as count
from sample
group by game_ball;
quit;
```

Comment: Your sql statement should not use the distinct keyword.  It should simply be `select game_ball, count(*) as count....`etc